# Why does this function fail

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm writing a function that receives two integer pointers, int* a and int* b. Set the value of a to their sum, and b to their absolute difference.
My output suppose  to be positive number (9, 5) but what I'm getting is zero(0,0).
Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
    int res1,res2; 
    res1=*a+*b;
    res2= *a-*b; 
    *a=res1; 
    *b=res2; 
}
int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa =&a,*pb = &b;
    scanf("&d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a , b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"&d %d"` -> `"%d %d"`

Comment: That mistake should even be noted by the compiler. Don't ignore the warnings. If you did not get some message about incorrect number of arguments, you should increase warning level.

Answer (score -3):

You have to verify what are you sending and manipulating so you can do something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
    int res1 ,res2;
    printf("\nDEBUG first : %d %d", &a, &b); 
    printf("\nDEBUG first : %d %d", *a, *b);

    res1=*a+*b;
    res2=*a-*b; 
    *a=res1; 
    *b=res2; 
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa =&a,*pb = &b;
    scanf("&d %d", &a, &b);

    printf("DEBUG Value of PA : %d , PB : %d",pa, pb);
    update(pa, pb);

    printf("%d\n%d", a , b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%p` should be used to print pointers instead of `%d`

Comment: It would be more important to check result of `scanf`. That would immediately show that only 1 value was parsed. Also the error is not fixed here. Still incorrect format string.